# Grouping Widgets to Scroll as One

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a widget tree that looks like this:

```
Scaffold(
  Column(
    Text()
    Expanded(ListView.builder)
    RaisedButton()
  )
)
```

The problem is that the ListView gets very big, and starts scrolling, but the top Text and the bottom RaisedButton stay still. (The same way a frozen row would in a spreadsheet)

The intended behavior is for everything to scroll as one like an HTML page.

I have tried using this on my ListView:

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
shrinkWrap: true,
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

just wrap your column with *SingleChildScrollView*

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(),
      ),
```

Comment: I tried using this but then I get an error:
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I do not specify the height of the child elements.